# LightInject: Call HttpPost Method

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, constructor

I have this class whit HTTPPost Method:

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly ILog _logger;

```
    public MyController(ILog logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    [Route("api/route/{Id}/Start")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Start(string Id)
    {
         ...
```

And in the BootStrap class I want to call the Start method. How can I do this?:

IServiceContainer _serviceContainer;

```
    public MyBootstrapper(IServiceContainer container)
    {
         container.RegisterConstructorDependency<ILog>((factory, info) => new InfoLogger(info.Member.DeclaringType));
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await RegisterServicesAsync();
    }

    protected static async Task RegisterServicesAsync()
    {
        IServiceContainer container = new ServiceContainer();
        container.Register<MyController>();

        using (container.BeginScope())
        {
             //I must call here?
```

That I want to do is call My Method from a console application:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {  
        Bootstrapper.RunAsync().Wait();
```

And in the Bootrapper call the Methods that I have in the different services.

Comment: This seems almost certainly the wrong way to go about whatever you're trying to do. Can you clarify what the actual goal is?

Comment: What is your intension here? In .net core you generally register everything from within your StartUp class. From within your Startup class you call your Bootstrap class. You can try adding (this IServiceContainer container) to you method signature so you can call it from the startup class.

Comment: I want to make a test from my Web API.

Comment: ah okay. try using Moq. It a wonderful way of faking injections for unit test. for integration testing take a look here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your approach may be misinformed.

In your startup class location this section

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // existing code

    // add this
    BootStrap.RegisterServices();
}
```

in your BootStrap file do something like this (updated your code). I would recommend removing the reset

```
public void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection collection)
{
    // or whatever required scope. AddSingleton, AddTransient, AddScoped
    collection.AddTransient<ISomeInterface, SomeImplementationOfISomeInterface>();
    ///...add more as needed
}
```

this is a good place to start
[Microsoft DI Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)